# SFML C++ gif анимация

Tags: c++, c, анимация, sfml

Доброго времени суток!
С принципом создания анимации из изображения я знаком, а есть способы использовать gif для воспроизведения анимации (sml)?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, такого функционала в SFML нет.
Вам необходимо вручную вытащить кадры из GIF анимации, а также периоды задержек кадров.